# Split 1 row into multiple fractional rows

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures, database-design, database-schema

I'm working on a restaurant POS system and I'm trying to devise a splitting system in order to split items into fractional quantities over multiple orders.

Here is simple summary of what I have so far:

I have a table of 'tables' with 'table_id' and 'table_number'. Each dining table can have multiple 'clients' with 'client_id' and 'client_number'. Each client is associated with an order from the table 'orders' with 'order_id' and, related with 'client_id'. Each order has multiple line items from the table 'line_items' with 'line_item_id' and 'quantity' related with 'order_id'.

So right now, I have a data structure of the likes:

```
tables: {
    table_id,
    table_number,

    clients: {
        client_id,
        client_number,
        table_id,

        orders: {
            order_id,
            client_id,

            line_items: {
                line_item_id,
                quantity,
                order_id,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I need to do now is to be able to split the line items into fractional quantities over multiple orders.

So an example would be: I have line_item 1 in order 1, and I'd like to split it as 1/2 in order 1 and 1/2 in order 2. If I split it again, I get 1/3 order 1, 1/3 order 2, 1/3 order 3.

I'm thinking of 2 solutions in order to achieve this:

1. I add an extra column for line_items for the 'denominator' and each time I split it, I create an extra line_item on the other order and update the denominator each time.
2. I create a table for the divided items called 'sub_line_items', when I first split the line_item into 2 halves, I add two records into 'sub_line_items' and relate them back with 'order_id' and 'line_item_id'.

Comment: That's 4 db tables.  Be sure to decide how to divide $1.00 into exactly 3 parts.

Comment: I think I'm expressing myself wrong here, I need to divide the line_item quantity into fractions and not decimals because fractions are more human readable. I need to be able to keep track of the original line_item in order to reconstitute it back into a whole number.

This is for situations where 1 customer orders 1 bottle a wine and a second one wants to pay half of it. I would then need to attribute 1/2 bottle to 1 order and 1/2 bottle to another order. If they decide to cancel the operation, I need to recombine it back into 1 line_item

Comment: If the "order" also included a corkscrew that was not to be shared, this gets messy.  That is, are you splitting an `order` or splitting a `line_item`?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a table of which clients are paying for each line_item.  It would have (perhaps) just 2 columns: client_id and line_item_id.

The number of clients for a given line_item_id would determine 1/2 vs 1/3, etc.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS denominator
    FROM splits
    WHERE line_item_id = 1234;
```

To revert from 1/3 to 1/2, simply delete a row.